# Can I use an outboard Shimano BB on a Trek madone ALR (alum.) with pressfit BB?

Tags: bottom-bracket

my 2015 Trek Modone ALR road bike has a press fit bottom bracket.   compared to my 2012 madone, the bottom bracket has much more drag.
I always liked the Shimano Hollowtech outboard bottom brackets and would like to install one on my TREK ALR.
Is there a conversion kit for this purpose?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No. The BB90 design puts the bearings the same distance apart that a normal external Shimano BB would, hence a normal Hollowtech 2 road crank being able to run on it.

It may be possible to make a BB386EVO adapter for BB90, but if so I don't think anyone's done it.

Comment: Given that FSA [doesn't make it](http://fsa-4207.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CRANKSET_BB-COMPATABILITY-CHART-ROAD-20160312.pdf), I don't think anyone does (or will).

Answer (score 1):

You can't stick a conventional Hollowtech (II) bottom bracket in a pressfit system. However, you can use a Hollowtech II crank in [some pressfit systems](http://www.bikeradar.com/us/gear/article/complete-guide-to-bottom-brackets-36660/).

If you're experiencing drag, make sure that the current bottom bracket has been installed properly (your shop can check this) or you can try replacing it with another bottom bracket which is compatible with your crank+frame.